# Spring security and username/password autofill in navigator

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

I've generated the following JSP spring security code for login form using Roo and gvnix addon. Authentication works fine but I can't get login autofill in navigators (Firefox, IE). they just propose to save an "X" username which I haven't set and nothing is proposed when going back on the form. I just can't find why the username I type is not saved... Any idea?
Thank you

```
 <div>
    <label for="j_username">
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_name"/>
    </label>
    <input id="username" name="j_username" style="width:150px" type="text"/> 
    <spring:message code="security_login_form_name_message" htmlEscape="false" var="name_msg"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <c:set var="sec_name_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${name_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
        </c:set>
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_username", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_name_msg}", required : true}})); 
    </script>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="j_password">
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_password"/>
    </label>
    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" style="width:150px" type="password"/>
    <spring:message code="security_login_form_password_message" htmlEscape="false" var="pwd_msg"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <c:set var="sec_pwd_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${pwd_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
        </c:set>
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_password", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_pwd_msg}", required : true}})); 
    </script>
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));</script>
    <spring:message code="button_submit" htmlEscape="false" var="submit_label"/>
    <input id="proceed" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From a security point of view auto-completion of usernames is considered bad practice.

Users are free to instruct their browsers to save their credentials information and use it in auto-complete action, but this behavior should not be enforced by applications.

Your requirement seems to be more related to browser specifics then Spring framework.

In general auto-completion of possible values means someone types a value and the auto-completion fetches all values that satisfy the criteria (e.g. starts with) from a storage. I guess you don't want someone to be able to pull out all your usernames from your storage using this auto-completion feature.

Comment: I don't get your point. Firefox saves all the usernames of many websites except my application one so I guess it's not related to Firefox but to my application.

Comment: Regarding the practice, I think that avoiding username and password autofill promote weak passwords

Comment: That's why in most places when you create a new account there are password restrictions like minimum length, required symbols etc.